# Error restoring Rancher: This cluster is currently Unavailable; areas that interact directly with it will not be available until the API is ready

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, rke

I am trying to backup and restore rancher server (single node install), as the [described here](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/backups/backups/single-node-backups/).

After backup, I tried to turn off the rancher server node, and I run a new rancher container on a new node (in the same network, but another ip address), then I [restored using the backup file](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/backups/restorations/single-node-restoration/).

After restoring, I logged in to the rancher UI and it showed the error below:

[image]

So, I checked the logs of the rancher server and it showed as below:

> 2019-10-05 16:41:32.197641 I | http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:38388: EOF
> 2019-10-05 16:41:32.202442 I | http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:38380: EOF
> 2019-10-05 16:41:32.210378 I | http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:38376: EOF
> 2019-10-05 16:41:32.211106 I | http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:38386: EOF
> 2019/10/05 16:42:26 [ERROR] ClusterController c-4pgjl [user-controllers-controller] failed with : failed to start user controllers for cluster c-4pgjl: failed to contact server: Get https://192.168.94.154:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system?timeout=30s: waiting for cluster agent to connect
> 2019/10/05 16:44:34 [ERROR] ClusterController c-4pgjl [user-controllers-controller] failed with : failed to start user controllers for cluster c-4pgjl: failed to contact server: Get https://192.168.94.154:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system?timeout=30s: waiting for cluster agent to connect
> 2019/10/05 16:48:50 [ERROR] ClusterController c-4pgjl [user-controllers-controller] failed with : failed to start user controllers for cluster c-4pgjl: failed to contact server: Get https://192.168.94.154:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system?timeout=30s: waiting for cluster agent to connect
> 2019-10-05 16:50:19.114475 I | mvcc: store.index: compact 75951
> 2019-10-05 16:50:19.137825 I | mvcc: finished scheduled compaction at 75951 (took 22.527694ms)
> 2019-10-05 16:55:19.120803 I | mvcc: store.index: compact 76282
> 2019-10-05 16:55:19.124813 I | mvcc: finished scheduled compaction at 76282 (took 2.746382ms)

After that, I checked logs of the master nodes, I found that the rancher agent still tries to connect to the old rancher server (old ip address), not as the new one, so it makes the cluster not available.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-register the node in Rancher using the following steps.

- Update the server-url in Rancher by going to Global -> Settings -> server-url
  This should be the full URL with https://
- Then use this script to re-register the node in Rancher https://github.com/mattmattox/cluster-agent-tool